# Remove wordpress comments counter in Admin dashboard

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

When I was cleaning my website from spams, I noticed a high number of comments (600+) in admin dashboard. Instead of going through one by one and deleting them, I decided to nuke all unapproved comments with this sql query:

```
delete from wp_comments where comment_approved = 0
```

Now my admin dashboard is STILL showing the same number of comments but all the actual comments are gone. How do I reset this counter back to zero.
[image: Comment Counter still not reset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer the SQL way, you can do:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count = 0 WHERE id = id
```

Or you have a wordpress function: `wp_update_comment_count( $post_id, $do_deferred )`

[WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_comment_count)

Comment: Accepted this answer as it might help someone. For my case, refer to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

For that pending comments you have to approve or reject to remove counter..!
you can use Bulk Actions for Approve at once ..!

[image]

Comment: Sadly, I do not even have that bulk action anymore as seen in screenshot.

Comment: Of course you don't, because you don't have comments. However, comment count was stored in the posts table (I think for performance reasons). So check my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as soon as new comments came in, the old counter disappear. The comment counter will just revert back to normal.

Comment: Have you tried wp_update_comment_count? Also this post might worth trying, it seems to do something with taxonomies and metas as well: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-category-and-comment-count-after-wordpress-import/